# List Iteration - List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been having challenges in finding a solution to remove an object from a list of dictionaries.

I have a script that makes two API calls; one to collect a list of locations and one to collect a list of devices. I use the device list to generate a variable to use as a search piece and this works fine.

The challenge I have is removing items from the list of locations. I'm unable to cleanly remove the object.

```
locationGroup = [{'URI': '/devce/33333', 'description': 'unique-location-2'}, {'URI': '/device/40593', 'description': 'unique-location-3'}, {'URI': '/device/50799', 'description': 'unique-location-7'}
```

My search string is a partial, but I need to be able to remove the dictionary based on the description. An example string that I'm able to generate is `location-7`

I've tried different variations on removal using `del` and `.remove()` with no success. Eg. `locationGroup['description'].remove(location-7)` as well as `del locationGroup['location-7']`

Comment: `[x for x in locationGroup if "location-7" not in x["description"]]`

Comment: `locationGroup` is a _list_. It's impossible to index it with anything else than an `int`. What you want to _find_ is a dictionary inside this list whose `'description'` field contains data _similar_ to `'location-7'`. How would you, a human, do this on a piece of paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a list of dictionaries as input, all with the `description` key. You want to keep only the dictionaries where the value corresponding to `description` hasn't a particular substring in it

So instead of trying to edit the list in-place, just rebuild the new list of dictionaries with a filter within a list comprehension:

```
locationGroup = [{'URI': '/devce/33333', 'description': 'unique-location-2'}, {'URI': '/device/40593', 'description': 'unique-location-3'}, {'URI': '/device/50799', 'description': 'unique-location-7'}]

result = [x for x in locationGroup if "location-7" not in x["description"]]

>>> result
[{'URI': '/devce/33333', 'description': 'unique-location-2'},
 {'URI': '/device/40593', 'description': 'unique-location-3'}]
```

you can assign it back directly to the original list name if you need to.

Comment: Got there before me! That's an elegant way of doing it